# How do I select every other even child and adjacent child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[Image attached for desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/804uO.png)

I want to select in order 2,3 then 6,7 and then 10 [Image attached for desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/804uO.png). So How do I select these with nth-child or something else? It'll go something like this...

(1)*(2)
(3)*(4)
(5)*(6)
(7)*(8)
(9)*(10)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with :nth-child using two formulas, one for the even numbers and one for the even ones. This is a working example of my suggestion:

```html
<style>
    li:nth-child(4n - 2), li:nth-child(4n - 1) { color: red; }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

The `4n` part provides the "every other even/odd" part you're looking for: it will select one every 4 items. The `-1` and `-2` offset this interval to match the numbers you want. You could get the inverse behaviour (select 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, etc) when using offsets `+1` and `0`

Comment: Thank you so much @agus-neira . It worked and You explained it very well too. I easily got it. :)